# Kendo editor react wrapper display an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-react-ui

I want to add an editor using Kendo UI. But I get an error `TypeError: list is undefined` in `node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/editor/plugins/inlineformat.js:422`

I installed the library using :

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-editor-react-wrapper
```

And this is my component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Editor } from '@progress/kendo-editor-react-wrapper';

class SLEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor value={this.state.value} height={500} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SLEditor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just need a configuration :

```
        <Editor
          value={this.value}
          height={500}
          tools={[
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'foreColor',
            'insertUnorderedList',
            'insertOrderedList',
            'createTable',
            'addColumnLeft',
            'addColumnRight',
            'addRowAbove',
            'addRowBelow',
            'deleteRow',
            'deleteColumn',
            'justifyLeft',
            'justifyCenter',
            'justifyRight'
          ]}
        />
```